# Sleeping time for running multiple function using python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am running a program which has many functions that need to be run every day at 00:00. I am using APSchedular and was wondering if there is need of sleeping time to run 10-20 functions exactly at 00:00 every day?
Here is my program;

```
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
sched = BlockingScheduler()
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=0, minute=0)
def ABC():
    path1 = ('C:\Users\ABC.tsv')
    date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    url2 = ("%sT00:00:00&to=%sT23:00:00"%(date,date))
    data2 = requests.get(url2)
    Z=zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(data2.content))
    Z.extractall()
    df1=pd.read_csv(path1, sep='\t',names = ["Datetime", "BAC"])
    df1['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df1['Datetime'])
    df1=df1.set_index('Datetime')
    df1=df1.resample('H',how='sum')
    ABC= df1.copy()
    ABCD= ABC* 0.519
    ABC.to_csv('C:\Users\ABC.tsv')
    ABCD.to_csv('C:\Users\ABCD.tsv')
    return
sched.start()
```

Also, APSchedular does not allow adding an argument to the function, is there any workaround to this? Please note: in the above example, I have also added one function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with APScheduler, where does it say that 20 functions will run? If it's 20 copies of this same function, you should note that, since every run is modifying the same file, multiple simultaneous runs may conflict with each other. They must run sequentially, not in parallel.

Comment: I have 20 different functions and all of them will produce different files. In the above example, I have only pasted one function.